# TypeScript - remove all properties with particular type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, mapped-types

I have a `type` which is used to project keys present in `T` to the common keys and the types thereof present in `U`:

```
type IntersectByCommonKey<T, U, V = any> = {
  [K in keyof U]: K extends keyof T ?
  T[K] extends V ?
  U[K]
  : T[K] extends object ?
  IntersectByCommonKey<T[K], U[K], V>
  : T[K] extends object | undefined ?
  IntersectByCommonKey<T[K], U[K], V> | undefined
  : never
  : never
};
```

[IntersectByCommonKey Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdsCAnAzhAxsAQiAwgewFtD84BpCEAHgBUAaKAVQYDUoBeKAQzhAD4OUAN4AoKFADaZKAEs4UANaV8AMyYBdAFxRpEAB6I4AExSLlamlAD8YqDSnqo+wyahsb4xg9vb7ZR84Qxqb4AEYAVhjA1rbwiKhROATEpBTUfuoMXv6sfD52Dk4GQa5hkZhQAD5QAK7GECpyEEYx4nHIaJhJRCTklLQOWYNuAtV1Rg1NRvlwEABuyDPziwC+ANwiIqCQdhAowDTg0Jyi4nBchBDa+0hyAOYb4kZciNoAIi8Qj7IoAEoQdxk+2QzW0oXw+AANhAeN90EQwNC9NpTuIoMioHAaoRQshvuIQNosTi8bYViJyVsjrt9odIAAFJD4crAGSkQSo86XKxgiHQ2G2Z6IHlQcFQmFwb5A-6A4FIZoisX8yW2eGERH6RV8iVVYS2cR6LXigVoqAgI3K77kykqOqYNnyMBMlm0IouUw0PYHI6M5lRB18AAUTr99tIvgAlNp2gkungeql+vQad7IAxgEgahABKiAPS5qAoIjQGTq6GXBAvB22eXAGpIeRCFbcUwxzrYeMpPrpBie2lHdOZ7MUza5gBUY7EY6gYFFGGLpgABkIoEKrlAPog1piLuvZgskNvpQCgfFQZjloeoGqNRiVxjibir4SLweoM2Voup7mRPC4PsZ0EEMWUDVE120DMszoVUESRFF9XRCChzJCkIxEIA)

where for each key `K` in `U`, if `T` has the same key `K`, and if the type at `K` `extends V`, includes the shape for that key, otherwise `never`.

With the type returned by `IntersectByCommonKey` I want to remove every key that has a `never` type which means it must cope with nested `Record` shapes too.

It's easy enough to remove top-level keys:

```
type ExcludeKeysWithTypeOf<T, V> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Exclude<T[K], undefined> extends V ? never : K 
}[keyof T]

type Without<T, V> = Pick<T, ExcludeKeysWithTypeOf<T, V>>;
```

[ExcludeKeysWithTypeOf Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgYwDYFcAmEDSEQGcDqAlsABYAq4EA8gGYA8ZANFAGoB8UAvFAN4BQUKAG1MUQgDsoAaxwB7GlDIBdAFyxEqDAxFLmKcRhoSIaDhDjAIB3KygB+KOIgA3CACcoa0XwC+QmSDyikp8fKCQUESksijADMzsXFAACoQIUvHqyOhYOATE5JS0mexsANyh4dBkELjAFBHc-ILiAIYAthBqdW4SAOYVgmitlmoAIiMQg2K4AEoQfYR17iZqAEayskgQreIVPpWUkQUxwADKwL3ifUlRJKcMtfWUzD39bGFHd6cTlrcnsUedQaEGYvwgHyqx2isQAQpttrt-jC4jVgS8oBstjtxGwgA)

However, I'm struggling to achieve the same result for nested `Record`s, is there a way I can recursively remove keys with types of `never`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to make recursive call to go into nested records types.
Here an example solution:

```
type Without<T, V, WithNevers = {
  [K in keyof T]: Exclude<T[K], undefined> extends V ? never 
  : (T[K] extends Record<string, unknown> ? Without<T[K], V> : T[K])
}> = Pick<WithNevers, {
  [K in keyof WithNevers]: WithNevers[K] extends never ? never : K
}[keyof WithNevers]>
```

The core idea is when our `T[K]` will have type of Record, it will recursively call again itself (`Without` type level function). The whole type will reduce to wanted form in which every nested object will have removed keys we wanted.

The whole code snippet - [the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgewK7ADwBUA0UBqe8SAchAG4QBOAzlALxQDeAUFFANoDSUcAdlADWEEMgBmULAF0AXFACiADwDGAG1QATCNm5S8qPlrH8IGgHxQIi4BEN18UAPxQ+FalDZQ5ACiy7L1rYadABKEMrIVBoYNMBU-ADm+nyCfMgA7nwWzsQo6DpcegQWcn6FAJQsAL4WjAAKcMqCGLlklLR4rOzcvALCohKtbrSysAiIbdQ0-lY2di7DTgvtXlBc1Rz94mOkwzRSZiwsoJCSELFY4NCMXS4AhgC2EHKx8XwJANyeGnc2cgAivwgX3YcBoYQSYJsVFMcgARshkKoIHc+CCoMg4QArOS3dh8R7PKCvRKeKrVI4naC5NDAADKcUSDB2eUwWHOwEukDwJPehwifFiUDuchp6AZbwSzNuPz+C3SUEBNm85RwnjBEKh1FhUDiqAgavYmJxzHJ5KpLNpSuulvy7IuVzw1v5yEFwCgcNF4ytQOlngJTzkAHJFEHDbxwRBIbFtRo5HqDZ5jbiA0SQ0GzUA)

**Note:** I moved calculating of `WithNevers` inside arguments list of the type in order to achieve better readability. We can also define it as separate type.